# Kartik/Krajee Select2 not disabled

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

Setting Select to to 'disabled' does not disable the element.  The user can still click on the text of Select2 and the options box opens up.  Here is a disabled control that was opened by clicking on the text and not the down-arrow button.

[image: Disabled Control:]

Here is my code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'billing_currency_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
'data' => BillingCurrency::listIdCodes('','',true),
'disabled' => true,
'options' => ['disabled' => true,],
'pluginOptions'=>[
    'allowClear'=>false,
    'dropdownAutoWidth'=>true,
    'disabled' => true,
], ]); ?>
```

Clicking on the down-arrow button keeps the control closed, but clicking on the text area of the control opens the options box.

**UPDATE**
Found my own mistake - see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake - I have some custom JS code on the site that opens the Select2 when it gets focus.  My code was causing the reported problem.
My custom code was created to overcome a limitation of Select2 whereby it does not automatically open when the user tabs into the control.  I've corrected the code.  When Select2 gets focus either from tab or from click, the control opens the popup UNLESS it is disabled.  (Previously I didn't have a check for the disabled attribute.)

```
$(document).on('focus', '.select2', function() {
    var elSelect = $(this).siblings('select');
    if (elSelect.is('[disabled]')==false) {
        elSelect.select2('open');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling select is described in official docs in [Examples (Disabled mode) section](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#disabled):

> Select2 will respond to the disabled attribute on `<select>` elements.
>   You can also initialize Select2 with disabled: true to get the same
>   effect.

As for Kartik's extension, you can set `'disabled' => true` under `options` section like this:

```
'options' => ['disabled' => true],
```

I checked just to be sure, and it works.

Comment: If you click on the text of the element does the popup open?

Comment: @readtheBook No, it's completely disabled and stop sign appears on hover.